# Javascript: Understanding Prototype chain

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I created a simple class as follows:

```
var Class = function() {};
Class.prototype.testObj = {a:2, b:3};
```

Now if I do `console.log(Class.testObj)` I get `undefined`. But if i create instance of that Class as follows:

```
var instance = new Class();
console.log(instance.testObj)
```

I get expected output.

In my understanding, all variables are treated as Objects and have prototype property. When some key is not found in the object, prototype chain is traversed to look for the key-value pair. But in case of Class, it is not traversing the prototype chain.

What am I missing? What additional does `new` keyword do such that property is accessible?

Comment: `Class.prototype` isn't part of the `Class` object's prototype chain. It's in the prototype chain of any objects created using `new Class()`.

Comment: So far I understand that setting prototype property of constructor function do not set those properties in prototype chain of that function. Is there any way to set properties in prototype chain explicitly?

Comment: `Class`' prototype chain consists of `Function.prototype` and `Object.prototype`, so you would need to modify one of those. I recommend against doing so unless you have a really good reason for it. Some JS engines will allow you to access `Class.__proto__` which is the prototype that `Class` inherits from, but this is not part of the ES spec and is also discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

1. You must be clear that `Class()` is your `constructor`, not an `instance object`. so `Class.testObject` will return `undefined` because `Class` doesn't have that `property`.
2. You can think of a `prototype` as a recipe for an object. Almost every function has a `prototype` property that is used during the creation of new instances and **that `prototype` is shared among all of the object instances**
3. A constructor is simply a function that is used with `new` to create an object
4. When you do this `var instance = new Class();` It means you are creating an instance object of `Class`, hence `instance` will inherit `prototype` properties of `Class`.
5. Test:

   ```
   console.log(instance instanceof Class); // => true

   console.log(instance.constructor === Class); // => true

   console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Class)); // => true

   console.log(Class.prototype.isPrototypeOf(instance)); // => true
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create an object, such as a function, it inherits from the Object constructor, so this

```
var Class = function() {};
```

is an object, and it has it's own `prototype` property that can be accessed with

```
Class.prototype
```

and you can create new properties on the `prototype` object with

```
Class.prototype.testObj = {a:2, b:3};
```

if you wanted to access that, you would actually have to do

```
console.log(Class.prototype.testObj)
```

as that's where it is, a property added to the `prototype` property of `Class`.

When you use the `new` keyword some magic happens, a whole new object is created (called an instance), and that object inherits from `Class.prototype`, from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

> When the code new Class(...) is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from Class.prototype.
> 2. The constructor function Class is called with the specified arguments
>      and `this` bound to the newly created object. new Class is equivalent to
>      new Class(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, Class is called
>      without arguments.
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result
>      of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't
>      explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
>      instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
>      process.)

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the relationship between `Class` and `Class.prototype`.

`Class` is a constructor. Strictly speaking, JavaScript does not differentiate between constructors and general purpose functions, but that's not important right now. `Class.prototype` is the prototype of *instances* of Class. That is to say, when you instantiate the class - `var x = new Class()` - `Class.prototype` is attached to `x` as a *delegate object*.

What this means is that lookups to x will propagate up the delegate chain, and reference variables on that prototype instance.

> In my understanding, all variables are treated as Objects and have prototype property.

This is incorrect. JavaScript has many primitive types, and only functions have a property named 'prototype'. Prototypical delegates are only attached to reference types (objects, arrays, and functions) when they are created using `new` with a constructor or the ECMAScript 5 `object.create()` notation.

Incidentally, `Class` does have a prototype delegate, as it's an instance of `Function()`. One instance of a delegate function method is `apply()`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, `Class` is not an instance of `Class`, it's an instance of `Function`, so why would it inherit `Class.prototype`? The first link in `Class`'s prototype chain is `Function.prototype`.

We can see that if we pick a function from `Function.prototype`, such as `call`, it exists on `Class`.

```
typeof Class.call; //function
```

Object instances have their prototype chain setup with their constructor's prototype. Therefore, nnly objects that are instances of `Class` will have their prototype chain setup with `Class.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

You added the object to the `prototype`,
If you did `console.log(Class.prototype)`, you would see the object.

The `new` keyword instantiates the object, which brings out properties attached to its prototype as properties of the instantiated object.
Because the newly instantiated object is actually inheriting the `prototype` of the parent object, not the parent object itself.